# Dynamically change from/to values used in animations

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qtquick2

Say I've got the following code:

```
Rectangle {
  id: rect

  property int minVal : 0
  property int maxVal : 10
  property int duration: 1000

  SequentialAnimation {
    loops: Animation.infinite
    NumberAnimation {
       target: rect; property: "x"
       from: minVal;  to: maxVal
       duration: duration
    }
    NumberAnimation {
       target: rect; property: "x"
       from: maxVal;  to: minVal
       duration: duration
    }
  }
}
```

Then later, I hook up this object's `minVal`, `maxVal`, and `duration` properties to sliders, so that I can play around with this effect.

Is there any way to force the animation to use the new values for min/maxVal?

Currently, it seems that the `minVal`/`maxVal` values present when the animations were initialised get "baked" into the animations, with no way to force these to get recalculated/rebaked later

Previously I've been able to get away with throwing away the entire QML canvas everytime one of these changes was needed. But in this case, it's not really practical, so I was wondering if there were other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way to 'bake' in those values. For me, at least, this works as I expected:

```
Button {
    id: but
    property int count: 0
    property int minX: 0
    property int maxX:  1000

    text: 'start' + x

    onCountChanged: {
        minX += 10
        maxX -= 10
    }

    onClicked: ani.start()
}

SequentialAnimation {
    id: ani
    NumberAnimation {
        target: but
        property: 'x'
        from: but.minX
        to: but.maxX
    }
    ScriptAction {
        script: { but.count += 1 }
    }
}
```

I tried as much as possible to avoid bindings that could be baked in somehow.
Have I missed your problem?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo: Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Usually people gets piss off by being edited, I'm glad that's not the case.

Comment: It turns out that there were several things going on in the problematic system I had earlier: 1) As inspired by this answer, I added "on[Var]Changed" handlers to each of the properties the animation depended on, which would do anim.restart();   2)There were a few typos which were silently erroring out when the objects in question couldn't be found;   3) I had to play around with the order that the settings were getting flushed  (e.g. duration properties must come last!)

Comment: Oh, and for some bizarre reason, "maxVal" flushing had to occur before "minVal", or else 'maxVal' wouldn't get applied - since maxVal was the only thing that really changed/mattered, it was important to get that working.